# Get correct type value from json dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, key-value-coding

is there a way in objectivec to get **exact value type** from a json dictionary?

For example, consider this json:

```
{
    "ret": 0,
    "state": "Italy",
    "lat": 45.46347,
    "lon": 9.19404
}
```

I want to get `INT` value for "*ret*", `NSString` value for "*state*", and `FLOAT` value for "*lat*" and "*lon*".

I'm using this snippet:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sampleJson.json"]];
NSDictionary *dict = [ NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil ];

id val = [ dict valueForKeyPath:@"lat" ][0];

NSLog(@"%@", [val class] );
```

but obviously, the output is a generic `NSNumber`.

> 2014-01-31 11:13:51.903 Test0002[2044:70b] __NSCFNumber

It's possible to get a `float` instead of `NSNumber`, automatically?

Comment: try id val = [dict valueForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:@"lat"]];

Comment: @OptimusPrime what? Have you read the question?

Comment: int ret = [[dict valueForKey:@"ret"] intValue];

Comment: No man, you don't understand. Json are dynamics, i want something generic. See the question below to make an idea.

Comment: you can convert int to NSNumber.. NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:ret];

Comment: do you want to check if the number is NSNumber or int before you parse the json? Do you just want float instead of NSNumber? float num = [((NSNumber)val) floatValue];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the NSNumber is float or int, you can use this method:

```
    if ([val isMemberOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
    {
        switch(CFNumberGetType((CFNumberRef((NSNumber)val))
        {
          /* List of results:
          kCFNumberSInt8Type
         kCFNumberSInt16Type
         kCFNumberSInt32Type
         kCFNumberSInt64Type
         kCFNumberFloat32Type
         kCFNumberFloat64Type
         kCFNumberCharType
         etc... */
        }
    }
```

Once you found the type, just use:

```
float f = [((NSNumber)val) floatValue];
```

or

```
int i =[((NSNumber)val) intValue];
```

Find the whole list here:

[CFNumber Ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFNumberRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001209-CH203-DontLinkElementID_6)

To check that it's a NSString, just do:

```
if([val isMemberOfClass:[NSString class]])
{
}
```